# How to override the UIBarButtonItem triggered segue defined in a storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, uistoryboard

I have a UIViewController in a storyboard iPhone app that I need to reuse in several places. In the storyboard, there is a UIBarButtonItem that has a triggered segue to another controller. In some cases, however, I would like to override the behavior of the button to segue to a different view controller. I'm thinking that there must be a way to either initialize the view controller with a message that specifies the target view controller, or to set some property after the controller is initialized but before it's pushed?

One challenge seems to be that segues can't be defined programmatically (based on what I've read so far), and I don't think I can have multiple segues on the same view controller in storyboard. So I may need to do something like this:

```
[self presentModalViewController:myNewVC animated:YES];
```

... rather than use a segue, but I'm not sure how to override the behavior of the button defined in storyboard to do it that way.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create an `IBAction` and a `BOOL` for some condition to pick which view controller should be instantiated.

```
 UIViewController *viewController;
    if (someCondition) {
        viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someViewID"];
    }else{
        viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someOtherID"];
    }
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```